# Enthought Canopy not opening after splash page

Tags: python, windows, installation, canopy

I installed Enthought Canopy using the "canopy-2.1.7.win-x86_64-cp35.msi" file (from the official website).

Bacause my username does use non-ASCII charecters I used the guide linked from the install wizard:
(https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469830-Canopy-GUI-requires-extra-setup-steps-when-user-s-home-path-contains-non-ASCII-characters)

Now, when I open Canopy from the desktop shortcut or from the installation folder I **see the splash page for a few seconds and after it disappears nothing is happening.**

I am using Windows 10, 64 bit system.